# Add smaller, collapsible question feed option for chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

Room owners and chat moderators can add feeds to chat rooms that can e.g. display new questions from the target site. It's a very nice feature in my opinion, but it can get problematic for high traffic feeds and low traffic chat rooms.

When a question is posted to chat by the feed it looks like this:

[image]

The questions take up quite a bit of space, and as the feeds only fetch new questions every 10 or 20 minutes (not sure about the exact value), it is not unusual to have several questions posted at once. Having a block of questions that pretty much fill the height of my browser window posted in the middle of a chat conversation is not really ideal.

Now, I'll probably be reminded that this kind of feed should not be used for high-volume feeds, and the ticker feed should be used for that. The problem with the ticker feed is

1. You can't reply to the ticker feed. I find replying to feeds useful to make clear that I'm commenting on this particular question, with the ticker feed I'd have to post the question first in chat before I can do that.
2. For some reason I find the ticker feed obtrusive, probably because I have to take an action to dismiss it.

I propose to add a third feed option that posts questions as real chat messages, but in a minimized and more space efficient format, with the option to expand to the full teaser.

A single question posted by the feed would look like this:

[image]

Only the title would be displayed, with the arrowhead button to expand it to the full teaser.

If multiple questions are posted by the feed (or nobody posted anything between two feed messages) it would look like this:

[image]

Only a certain number of posts would be shown with title, all the other ones would be hidden by default. Maybe an "expand all" button would also be nice.

This should allow to use the non-ticker feeds for medium- to high-traffic feeds without disrupting the chat too much.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bookmarklet that collapses(and continues to collapse) all the post-oneboxes posted by users withe a negative userid:

```
javascript:(function(){window.hidePosts=function(){$("div.user-container.monologue").filter(function(){return!!this.className.match(/user--/ig)}).not(':has(div[class="annoying-collapse"])').find('.message:has(div[class="onebox ob-post"])').each(function(){$(this).find(".content").prepend('<div class="annoying-collapse"><a href="javascript:void(0)">(Show/hide)</a>  </div>');var a=$(this).find(".ob-post-title").clone().removeClass("ob-post-title").addClass("posttitle").css("display","inline");$(this).find(".annoying-collapse").append(a);$(this).find(".annoying-collapse a").click(function(){$(this).parents(".content").find("div.onebox.ob-post").toggle()});$(this).find("div.onebox.ob-post").hide()})};hidePosts();hidePosts.inter=setInterval(hidePosts,1e3)})()
```

[image]

This sort of solves the problem, but I'd like to see some SE support for this. More feed configuration options would be awesome!