# Ability to minimize oneboxes in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, onebox

Often times chatrooms can get overrun by oneboxes. Room owners and mods can move irrelevant oneboxes to a bin but sometimes these messages **are** relevant and shouldn't be binned.

It would be really great if there was a way to minimize them client-side with the ability to maximize them if needed.

This will be incredibly helpful for things like [book referrals from amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cy3K.jpg) that, quite frankly, can be huge.

Take the following screenshot for example:
[image: Example before minimized]

Minimizing the first youtube onebox could look something like this:
[image: Example after minimized]

Related:
[Make chat oneboxing smaller and less obnoxious - click to enlarge instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158524/make-chat-oneboxing-smaller-and-less-obnoxious-click-to-enlarge-instead)

<sub>**inb4 duplicate**: I am not suggesting we make them smaller by default, I am requesting a feature to completely minimize them onclick and not change default settings</sub>

Comment: I've a related, older feature request for [collapsible question feeds in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130696/add-smaller-collapsible-question-feed-option-for-chat).

Comment: minimize all the things!

Comment: Sounds like a chance for someone to make a userscript (and get a ton of Meta upvotes ;))

Comment: Yeah, those oneboxes look _really_ relevant...

Comment: way to miss the point @LightnessRacesinOrbit ;]

Comment: @TravisJ Although similar, that's not a dupe as the one you linked is targeting comments. This is specifically targeting oneboxes.

Answer (score 17):

[User scripts to the rescue!](https://gist.github.com/DaveRandom/7201629)

Works exactly as specified above:

---

*Collapse*:

[image: collapse]

---

*Expand*:

[image: expand]

---

So far I've only tested this in Chrome but I expect it to work in any (sane) environment. I've thrown this together pretty quickly, so there may be a few gremlins. If you see anything that doesn't work in the wild, let me know - preferably with a reproducible example ;-)

---

**Updated**

- Now fixes avatar sizes after show/hide operation
- Use jQuery animations a bit more effectively (apparently I forgot how it works)
- Link text for oneboxed historical chat messages now includes domain

Comment: +1 this looks fantastic

Comment: @CarrieKendall Updated with a few general improvements

Comment: Great! Though, in the case of a link to a Stack Exchange question, would it be possible to retain the title of the question in place of a truncated site url?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Sure. The URL shortening logic just mirrors what SE does with links that are not oneboxed (clips it to 30 chars), but that is a little over-zealous in my view. The easiest way to adjust it to suit your needs with but to change [this line](https://gist.github.com/DaveRandom/7201629#file-onebox-collapse-user-js-L30) in such a way that `maxLength` is a more sensible (larger) value. If you want to handle SE questions as a special case, that function would also be the place to add some custom code.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to give this a try too,

http://i.imagebanana.com/img/us8cehup/2013102914_48_09Sandbox_chat.stackov.png

*Three collaped oneboxes and one expanded.*
<sub>*I added the toggle to the right side, as I don't see an hover menu for my own messages*</sub>

If actually anyones ever going to use this. The text for the label is computed by the `getLabel` function. It gets called with the onebox element to generate the label for, feel free to parse information from it.

---

No jQuery, pure JavaScript only.<sub>Tested only in Chrome 32 and IE 11</sub>

```js
(function () {
var chat = document.getElementById ("chat");
var oneboxes = chat.getElementsByClassName ("onebox"); 
var _userContainer = window.userContainer;
var _updateUserContainer = window.updateUserContainer;


function minimizeOneboxes (boxes) {
  var hasToggle, toggle, label, labelEle, container, classList;


  for (var i=0,j; j=oneboxes [i] ; i++) {
     classList = [].join.call ( j.classList, " ");

     hasToggle = !!~ classList.indexOf ("onebox-toggle");
     if (!hasToggle) {
        show = document.createElement ("a" )
        hide = document.createElement ("span");

        show.innerHTML = getLabel (j) + " onebox.";
        hide.innerHTML = " ▼ ";

        container = [].pop.call (j.parentElement.parentElement.children);

        j.parentElement.insertBefore (show, j);
        container.insertBefore (hide, container.children [0]);

        j.style.display = "none";
        j.className += " onebox-toggle";        

        hide.addEventListener ("click",toggleBox);

     }
  }
}

function getLabel (ele) {
        var classList = [].join.call ( ele.classList, " ");
        label = classList .split ("-").slice (1);
        for (var k = 0,l=label.length; k<l; k++) {
            var cur = label [k];
            label [k] = cur.slice (0,1).toUpperCase () + cur.slice (1)
        }
        return label.join ("");
}

function toggleBox (e) {
   var source = e.srcElement || e.target;
   var target = source.parentElement.parentElement.children [1]
   var hidden = target.children [1].style.display === "none";

   source.innerHTML = hidden ?   " ▲ " : " ▼ ";

   target.children [0].style.display = hidden ? "none" : "";
   target.children [1].style.display = hidden ? "" : "none";
}

minimizeOneboxes (oneboxes);

if (!window.NoOneboxes) {

    window.userContainer = function () {

        oneboxes = chat.getElementsByClassName ("onebox");
        oneboxes.length && minimizeOneboxes (oneboxes);

        return _userContainer.apply (this, arguments);
    };
    window.updateUserContainer = function () {
        oneboxes = chat.getElementsByClassName ("onebox");
        oneboxes.length && minimizeOneboxes (oneboxes);

        return _updateUserContainer.apply (this, arguments);
    };
    window.NoOneboxes = true;
}
})()
```